# django forms is_valid() method always returning true if all the form field's required is false

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms, django-formtools

models.py created a model registerForm.my database is mysql.

```
from django.db import models

class registerForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50 )
    username = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'userForm'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets
from login_and_logout.models import registerForm

class regForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(regForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # there's a `fields` property now
        self.fields['name'].required = False
        self.fields['username'].required = False
        self.fields['email'].required = False
        self.fields['password'].required = False

    class Meta: 
        model = registerForm
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
check form is valid using is_valid() method 
    def signup(request):
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = regForm(request.POST)

            print(form.is_valid())
    
            if form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponse('success')
            else:
                return  HttpResponse('fail')
        form = regForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

i trying to implement form validation using javascript in client side and serverside validation in dajngo . in order to acheive form validation without required attribute
i give required false in dajngo forms.py. but after the is_valid() method always returning true. but if i remove the init funtion i used to remove requied field in forms.py the is_valid() works.
i want to remove the required field and also i want to work the is_valid() method.

Comment: ```is_valid``` is returning True for what request data can you paste that as well.

Comment: the method is post . after the is_valid() method in the views i get the values using  clean_data method this was the output {'name': 'sha', 'username': '', 'email': '', 'password': ''} . iam just fill the name field others fields leave empty in the form.but validation  not working at server side. if  i use required false in forms.py.after removing it will work. after set required false is valid always returning true.

Comment: I think you are not checking for validation that is why its returning true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print(print(form.is_valid()) statement for valid form wasn't under any conditional statement to check whether the condition was fulfil for saving a valid form, that was why it return True.

```
 def signup(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = regForm(request.POST)
            # This where your conditional check for valid form starts from
            # So you are suppose to put the print statement below the condition if statement 
            # All the logic of validations starts from the if statement
            if form.is_valid():
                print(form.is_valid())
                data = form.save(commit=False)
                data.username = request.user 
                # whatever data that you want to check for validation  before saving it.
                data.save()
                return HttpResponse('success')
            else:
                return  HttpResponse('fail')
        form = regForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```